# I am having problems inserting data in my database tables , and passing information from android studio to database

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

Below is my register class for user registration that, in the class  when the user clicks register it gets the information from the field and passes it to register request (register request code posted below ), i do not  get anything added to the tables after executing my code in android studio.

```
package com.example.user.emaillogin;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    final EditText etemail =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etemail);
    final EditText etpassword =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpassword);
    final EditText etname =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etname);
    final Button buttonregister =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonregister);

    buttonregister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String name = etname.getText().toString();
            final String email = etemail.getText().toString();
            final String password = etpassword.getText().toString();
            Response.Listener<String> ResponseListener = new   Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success =  jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if(success){
                            Intent intent = new   Intent(Register.this,MainActivity.class);
                            Register.this.startActivity(intent);
                        } else{
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new   AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Register failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            Registerrequest registerRequest = new Registerrequest(name,   email, password, ResponseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Register.this);
            queue.add(registerRequest);
        }
    });
}
}
```

this Register Request class allows me to make a request to my register.php(code posted below) file on the server and get response as a string and i have uploaded the php file to my server

```
package com.example.user.emaillogin;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by User on 07/02/2017.
 */

public class Registerrequest extends StringRequest {

private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL =    "http://picandlaugh.co.uk/register.php";
private Map<String, String> params;

public Registerrequest(String name, String email, String password,   Response.Listener<String> listener){

    super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("name",name);
    params.put("email",email);
    params.put("password",password);
}


@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}


}
```

below is my register.php code andi did include the actual host, username, password etc in the actual code but removed it for security purposes,

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("HOST", "USERNAME",  "PASSWORD", "DB");

$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["mail"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, " INSERT INTO WINKEL (name, mail, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $name, $email, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;  
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: What does `$statement->error` output?

Comment: It doees not output any error